# Can't access models from the script initialized in init.py

Tags: django, compiler-errors, mqtt, paho

Can U tell me how to access models before all the apps gets loaded
This is my `mqtt.py` which was initialized in `init.py` and accessing
models

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
from Transport.models import BusPosition

# Broker CONNACK response
def on_connect(client,userdata,flags,rc):
    print ("Connected with result code "+str(rc))

    # Subcribing to topic and recoonect for
    client.subscribe("trackrkct")


#Receive message

def on_message(client,userdata,msg):
    print(msg.topic+" "+str(msg.payload))

    BusPosition.create(1, "Mon, 23 May 2016 08:30:15 GMT", 11.0998, 77.9098)    

    client = mqtt.Client()
    client.on_connect = on_connect
    client.on_message = on_message

    client.connect("broker.hivemq.com",1883,60)
```

This is my init.py where mqtt.py was initialized

```
from kctsmarttransport import mqtt

mqtt.client.loop_start()
```

and this is my `models.py`

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

class BusPosition(models.Model):
    bus = models.ForeignKey(Bus)
    time = models.DateTimeField
    lat = models.FloatField(max_length=20)
    lng = models.FloatField(max_length=20)

    @classmethod
    def create(cls,bus,time,lat,lng):
        busPosition = cls(bus=bus,time=time,lat=lat,lng=lng)
        busPosition.save()

        return busPosition
```

and I got these errors as apps aren't loaded yet

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 2016.2.3\bin\runnerw.exe" C:\Users\Navin\DjangoProject\kct_transport_env\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Navin/DjangoProject/kctsmarttransport/manage.py runserver 5000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Navin/DjangoProject/kctsmarttransport/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Navin\DjangoProject\kct_transport_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Navin\DjangoProject\kct_transport_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 316, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "C:\Users\Navin\DjangoProject\kct_transport_env\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Users\Navin\DjangoProject\kct_transport_env\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Users\Navin\DjangoProject\kct_transport_env\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 97, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "c:\python27\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Users\Navin\DjangoProject\kctsmarttransport\kctsmarttransport\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from kctsmarttransport import mqtt
  File "C:\Users\Navin\DjangoProject\kctsmarttransport\kctsmarttransport\mqtt.py", line 2, in <module>
    from Transport.models import BusPosition
  File "C:\Users\Navin\DjangoProject\kctsmarttransport\Transport\models.py", line 6, in <module>
    class Bus(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\Navin\DjangoProject\kct_transport_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 105, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "C:\Users\Navin\DjangoProject\kct_transport_env\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 237, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "C:\Users\Navin\DjangoProject\kct_transport_env\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 124, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Yes. The documentation specifically warns against importing models from the `__init__.py`. Why are you starting your mqtt client there?

Comment: I need to listen the mqtt broker from ryt from the time my server starts without any blockage for the loop @DanielRoseman

Comment: Move the import inside the function so it only loads when executed which is probably after django has initialized.